# Is it possible to erase a DVD+R?

Tags: dvd, dvd-burning, disc

The disc is a Memorex DVD+R. It came half used and I would like it to be erased. It can be a physical procedure, **if necessary**. Maybe there is a way to take up all space and then virtually use it as empty?

Comment: If it’s not RW (DVD+/-RW) then that disc is done.

Comment: scratch it up with sandpaper and shatter it into as many peices as possible. then bury them at the 5 corners of the world, preferably guarded by Hydra's and Minotaurs and the like.

Answer (score 3):

*If* you have recorded the disk, and *if* you have not [finalized](https://www.cdrom2go.com/how-to-finalize-a-disc) it, it is possible to *add* more data, but not to erase it, AFAIK. However, if you received the disk from someone else and are able to read the data, then it *has* been finalized.

Finalization* puts support data, such as a permanent table of contents on the disk, rather than relying on a temporary one stored on the machine writing data to the disk.

* *Apparently, [DVD+VR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD%2BVR) does not require finalization.*

Comment: Hmm, in CD-R, iirc the ToC was always written to disc, but you could keep appending a new ToC that supersedes the old one (and "delete" files that way) unless the disc was finalized.

Answer (score 1):

In all seriousness, the best solution for most peoples needs is shredding. You can get a shredder pretty cheap at most any office supply store (most standard home/office shredders will do CD/DVDs). That would be an easy, reliable solution with reasonable security.

Secondly, if you are not too environmentally conscious, applying heat to the disk will corrupt and destroy the data. It's a pain to do, and is woefully irresponsible, but it provides a high degree of certainty that the data on a melted disk is unrecoverable against even the most powerful adversaries.

Scratching it up and breaking it is sufficient for most use-cases. It's not as convenient as a shredder, but its cheap and easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

Some DVD+R can be erased. The way to know if yours is one of them is:

- Open Windows Explorer
- Go to This PC
- Right-click the drive
- Check if you see the option of "Erase this disc".

If the option exists, then you may use it to erase the existing data.
Otherwise, it is not possible.

Comment: I thought they had to be DVD-RW/ DVD+RW?

Comment: @Moab: For RW I think this option is almost always available.